# Another way to say the possessive "one another's" or "each other's"

Tags: possessives

The possessive forms in "one another's" or "each other's" seems awkward as the "s" is given to just one part of the phrase. Is there any other way to say such possessives.

Example:

> Couples do not like to lose each other's trust.

Comment: *Couples do not like to lose trust in each other.*

Comment: Yes, but that is just an example. I want a way to use in different cases. And, first of all, do you agree that such possessives are awkward?

Comment: I don't believe it's awkward, but just about every sentence can be reworded to avoid unwanted phrasing - in general. In your example, however, it's really the *members of the couple* who lose each other's trust - not the couple *as a unit.* A better example would be *Teammates perform better when they have each other's trust.*

Comment: @Davo But "to lose A's trust" does not mean the same as "to lose trust in A". And that is what I mean in the example.

Comment: I have an additional question. Why does it sound extremely awkward to use *one another* as a subject? *One another are good.*

Comment: To *lose A's trust* means to *lose the trust of A* (not *in* A) - why would possessive be wrong here?

Comment: @Davo So should we say "they don't want to lose the trust of each other"? Is that idiomatic?

Comment: [Draw your own conclusions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+other+%27s+trust%2C+trust+of+each+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceach%20other%20%27%20s%20trust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrust%20of%20each%20other%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Sasan, *Couples do not like to lose each other's trust* is in no way undesirable.

If there's a problem here, it's what you might mean by *the "s" is given to just one part of the phrase*… Could you rephrase that at least two different ways, please?

Answer (score 1):

> Couples do not like to lose **mutual** trust.

**Mutual** (adj.)

> **1**
> **a**: directed by each toward the other or the others
>
> *Mutual affection*
>
> **b**: having the same feelings one for the other
>
> *They had long been mutual enemies* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutual)

---

> When people marry, most enter the union with an expectation that they
> have found the one person with whom they can share **mutual trust,
> love, and respect** until the end of time.
> [Thelma Duffey; "Divorce and
> Other Loss Issues in Family Therapy" in David Capuzzi and Mark
> Stauffer (eds.); *Foundations of Couples, Marriage, and Family Counseling*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yEUoEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA364&dq=couples%20lose%20mutual%20trust&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBoeTikZCEAxXWFVkFHRrSCf0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=couples%20lose%20mutual%20trust&f=false) (2021)

Answer (score 1):

... lose trust in each other (as the comment by Davo suggested)

Examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lose%20their%20trust%20in%20each%20other%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=d3e75792890ecf3a&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0-YD9LiAtvcs2bXE3JjcqHJrpxvdw:1708597543797&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf0aXt3b6EAxXQnokEHYYFC_EQ0pQJKAV6BAgHEAg&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1).

But with regard to "one another's" being awkward, no, it's not. It's idiomatic.

> They tried  out one another's bicycles.
>
> They had been married for a long time and knew one another's faults.
>
> Sometimes roommates get on one another's nerves.